# A Set of Objects with optional String properties, Improving a function that takes String arguments and finding the best match within the Set

Tags: swift, algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

We're trying to optimize some "weighted" matching algorithm we've been using, and decided to consult the internet for some more ideas

We have a Struct `MyStruct`, with 5 optional properties (in swift, this just means that the property can be `nil`):

```
prop1: String?
prop2: String?
prop3: String?
prop4: String?
prop5: String?
```

then we have an set of `MyStruct` (guaranteed that there aren't 2 instances that have the same exact properties),

`structArray: Set<MyStruct>`

we have a function that takes this array, as well as the 1-5 properties in a dictionary, to return 1 single instance that best matches.  If any of the properties don't match, the instance is taken out of contention immediately

```
func findBestMatch(forSet set:Set<MyStruct>, andArgs argDict:[String:String]) -> MyStruct? {
  //Will use this to store any matches, as well as an associated match score
  var bestMatch: MyStruct?
  var topScore = 0
  for element in set {
    var score = 0
    if let p1 = argDict["p1"] {
      if p1 == element.prop1 {
        score += 16 //p1 match has highest weight
      } else {
        continue
      }
    }

    if let p2 = argDict["p2"] {
      if p2 == element.prop2 {
        score += 8 //p2 match has second-highest weight
      } else {
        continue
      }
    }

    //etc for the other 3 properties

    if score > topScore {
      topScore = score
      bestMatch = element 
    }
  }
  return bestMatch
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```
exInstance1
  prop1 = "no good"
  prop2 = nil
  prop3 = "goodbye

exInstance2
  prop1 = "hello"
  prop2 = "noproblem"
  prop3 = "goodbye"

exInstance3
  prop1 = nil
  prop2 = nil
  prop3 = "goodbye"

exampleSet: Set<MyStruct> = [exInstance1, exInstance2, exInstance3]

matchingProperties: [String:String] = {
  "p1": "hello",
  "p3": "goodbye"
}


findBestMatch(forSet: exampleSet, andArgs: matchingProperties)
```

exInstance1 only has 1 match, on prop3, but because prop1 doesn't match at all, exInstance is not given a score

exInstance2 matches on both properties, and is given a score of 20

exInstance3 matches on one property, and is given a score of 4

exInstance2 is chosen and returned

---

**Question: Is there a better way to do this? If not, are there any ways we could improve this algorithm?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only see a slight improvement if you factor out the dictionary accesses outside the for loop, e.g.

```
func findBestMatch(forSet set:Set<MyStruct>, andArgs argDict:[String:String]) -> MyStruct? {
    //Will use this to store any matches, as well as an associated match score
    var bestMatch: MyStruct?
    var topScore = 0
    let p1 = argDict["p1"]
    let p2 = argDict["p2"]  // and so on
    for element in set {
        var score = 0
        if let p1 = p1 {
            if p1 == element.prop1 {
                score += 16 //p1 match has highest weight
            } else {
                continue
            }
        }

        //etc for the other properties

        if score > topScore {
            topScore = score
            bestMatch = element
        }
    }
    return bestMatch
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the following optimizations are possible:

1. Do not use a dictionary. Instead, pass the arguments directly.
2. At each iteration of the loop is used optional binding for each property. This can be avoided.
3. If all the fields of the object are not optional and equal to those passed to function, it is the best.

Based on the above, I propose the following solution:

```
import Foundation

struct MyStruct {
    var prop1: String? = nil
    var prop2: String? = nil
    var prop3: String? = nil
}

extension MyStruct: Hashable {}

func findBestMatch(for set: Set<MyStruct>,
                   oProperty1: String? = nil,
                   oProperty2: String? = nil,
                   oProperty3: String? = nil) -> MyStruct?
{
    let mask000 = 0b00000000
    let mask001 = 0b00000001
    let mask010 = 0b00000010
    let mask011 = 0b00000011
    let mask100 = 0b00000100
    let mask101 = 0b00000101
    let mask110 = 0b00000110
    let mask111 = 0b00000111

    var mask = mask000

    if let _ = oProperty1 {
        mask |= mask001
    }
    if let _ = oProperty2 {
        mask |= mask010
    }
    if let _ = oProperty3 {
        mask |= mask100
    }

    if mask == mask000 {
        return nil
    } else if mask == mask001 {
        let prop3 = oProperty3!
        return set.first(where: { $0.prop3 == prop3 })
    } else if mask == mask010 {
        let prop2 = oProperty2!
        return set.first(where: { $0.prop2 == prop2 })
    } else if mask == mask011 {
        let prop2 = oProperty2!
        let prop3 = oProperty3!
        return set.first(where: { $0.prop2 == prop2 && $0.prop3 == prop3 })
    } else if mask == mask100 {
        let prop1 = oProperty1!
        return set.first(where: { $0.prop1 == prop1 })
    } else if mask == mask101 {
        let prop1 = oProperty1!
        let prop3 = oProperty3!
        return set.first(where: { $0.prop1 == prop1 && $0.prop3 == prop3 })
    } else if mask == mask110 {
        let prop1 = oProperty1!
        let prop2 = oProperty2!
        return set.first(where: { $0.prop1 == prop1 && $0.prop2 == prop2 })
    } else if mask == mask111 {
        let prop1 = oProperty1!
        let prop2 = oProperty2!
        let prop3 = oProperty3!
        return set.first(where: { $0.prop1 == prop1 && $0.prop2 == prop2 && $0.prop3 == prop3 })
    }
    return nil
}

let exInstance1 = MyStruct(prop1: "no good", prop2: nil, prop3: "goodbye")
let exInstance2 = MyStruct(prop1: "hello", prop2: "noproblem", prop3: "goodbye")
let exInstance3 = MyStruct(prop1: nil, prop2: nil, prop3: "goodbye")

let exampleSet: Set<MyStruct> = [
    exInstance1,
    exInstance2,
    exInstance3,
]

if let object = findBestMatch(for: exampleSet, oProperty1: "hello", oProperty2: nil, oProperty3: "goodbye") {
    print(object) // print MyStruct(prop1: Optional("hello"), prop2: Optional("noproblem"), prop3: Optional("goodbye"))
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

We will analyze step by step on your example:

1. `mask = 000`
2. `oProperty1 != nil`. => `mask = mask | 100 = 000 | 100 = 100`
3. `oProperty2 == nil`. => `mask = 100`
4. `oProperty3 != nil`. => `mask = mask | 001 = 100 | 001 = 101`
5. `(mask == mask101) == true`. =>

   ```
   let prop1 = oProperty1!
   let prop3 = oProperty3!
   return set.first(where: { $0.prop1 == prop1 && $0.prop3 == prop3 })
   ```